# Book with solved examples and exercise problems for SUSY

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, education

I am learning supersymmetry right now. I am mostly following Bailin and Love. I try to connect all the steps from the book and complete the derivations in order to get comfortable with the calculations but I feel the lack of a problem book with a lot of solved and unsolved problems, something like the Schaum's series which I can use together with Bailin and Love. Do you happen to know any such book that you think would be helpful for me?

Comment: Probably not what you're referring to (also I'm not familiar with the texts you mention), but if you're looking for exercises in the supersymmetric method in quantum mechanics (see section 2 of http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405029) some classic examples are finding the super-partner potentials to the infinite square well and hydrogen, and use the formalism of the supersymmetric method to solve for their spectra and associated eigenstates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I browsed through the paper that you suggested. Although it is very interesting, what I am looking for is slightly different. I am searching for something which has solved and unsolved problems on supersymmetric gauge field theories, spontaneous supersymmetry breaking, supergravity and so on. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah I see. That's way beyond me at the moment. I'm a second year undergraduate and I just wrote a research paper for a quantum class I'm taking about the supersymmetric method described in section 2 of that paper. Good luck with your study of field theory!

Comment: Saved comment from @[AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/27384/anarchist-birds-worship-fungus): Course on [SUSY with exercises and solutions](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2009f/396T.html) posted online. God tier material.

Answer (score 4):

*Supergravity* by *Daniel Z Freedman* and *Antoine Van Proeyen* is quite excellent for illustrating Clifford algebra techniques and calculations in the classical SUSY/SUGRA in general(in the component formalism). The book has several calculations illustrated and plenty of exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem book, but *Supersymmetry: an Introduction with Conceptual and Calculational Details* by M\"uller-Kirsten and Wiedemann may be helpful. From the preface:

> "The text was compiled with the belief that the
>   majority of potential readers is more interested in actually using or applying supersymrnetry in some model theory
>   than in painstakingly rediscovering the results of others
>   for themselves, It seemed plausible, therefore, to revise
>   various relevant concepts and in particular, to include
>   the proof or verification of almost every formula. In this
>   way the reader can select the problems he wants to tackle
>   himself, compare his solutions with the calculations given
>   here, and thus gain the confidence in his own calculations
>   which he needs for his discussions of supersymmetry in
>   other contexts."

Citation information here: https://inspirehep.net/record/18778?ln=en

Answer (score 2):

A [valuable book on line](http://www.desy.de/~reuter/downloads/marialaach_susy07.pdf) from Jürgen Reuter with exercises on subjects as diverse as :

> - SUSY Field Theory
> - Symmetry and Algebra
> - Superfields and Superspace
> - Supersymmetric Lagrangians
> - SUSY Gauge Theories
> - SUSY breaking
> - The Minimal Supersymmetric SM (MSSM)
> - Gauge Coupling Unification
> - The MSSM Higgs sector
> - The Sfermions
> - Charginos, Neutralinos, Gluino
> - Models for SUSY-breaking communication
> - SUSY Phenomenology
> - MSSM Higgs searches
> - SUSY at colliders – Sparticle searches
> - SUSY Simulations
> - Electroweak precision observables
> - Muon anomalous magnetic moment
> - MSSM Dark matter

Answer (score 1):

[Course on SUSY](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2009f/396T.html) with exercises and solutions posted online. God tier material.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which is generally frowned on [>:( ] <-- See? It's frowned on. Consider adding a summary to accompany the link in case it gets dead and renders your answer useless

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142705)

Comment: @heather jim  I do understand that for a question which has an answer that is found in a link, posting the link is not correct since the whole point of the site is to provide answers here, not to give links with the answers. However, OP does not post a question, he wants a reference. You say "include the essential parts" am I supposed to copy all solved exercises and solutions on the link which are dozens of pages?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus, see the answer to [this meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) for information about this. Provide details about your resource, etc. The banner right below this question details this as well: "Please write substantial answers that detail the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others."